# Prove parallel line is tangent to second circle

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Two circles $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ have centers $O_1,O_2$. Let $\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2=A,B$, with $A\neq B$. An arbitrary line through $B$ intersects $\Gamma_1$ at $C$ and $\Gamma_2$ at $D$. The tangents to $\Gamma_1$ at $C$ and to $\Gamma_2$ at $D$ intersect at $M$. Let $N=AM\cap CD$. Let $l$ be a line through $N$ parallel to $CM$, and let $l\cap AC=K$. Prove that $BK$ is tangent to $\Gamma_2$.

---

$\qquad\quad$ [image]

---

Here is some progress I have:

We are looking to prove $\angle O_2BP=90^{\circ}$, and since $\angle O_2DP=90^{\circ}$, if we could prove $BP=PD$, we would be done by congruent triangles. So we are looking to prove $\dfrac{\sin \angle BDP}{\sin \angle DBP}=1$. Let $AM\cap BK=l$. We have $\angle BDP=\angle QBN$. By the law of sines on  $\triangle DNM,\triangle BNQ$, we have $\sin \angle BDP=\sin \angle NDM=\dfrac{NM}{DM}\sin \angle DNM$ and $\sin\angle QBN=\dfrac {NQ}{BQ}\sin\angle BNQ$. Dividing, the sines cancel (since they are supplementary), and we are left with $\dfrac{NM\times BQ}{DM\times NQ}$, so it remains to prove $\dfrac{NM}{DM}=\dfrac{NQ}{BQ}$.

I'm not sure what to do from here. We would be done if we could prove $\triangle NBQ\sim\triangle NDM$, but this would imply $\angle QNB=\angle MND=90^{\circ}$, but from drawing multiple diagrams, it looks like this is not always the case.

As always, any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us temporarily remove some of the distracting lines first so that we can use the following diagram to show ADMC is cyclic.

[image]

That claim is true because $x + (y_1) + [z_1] = x + (y_2) + [z_2] = 180^0$.

Now we add back the lines KB, ANM, KN.

[image]

From the fact that “$z_3 = z_1 = z_ 2$”, we can say $KN // CM$.

From the fact that "$\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \angle 3 = \angle 4$”, we can conclude that KB is tangent to the circle ADB.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $E$ be the intersection of tangent to $\Gamma_2$ at $B$ with $AC$. Our goal is to show $E=K$, i.e. $NE\|CM$. For that, prove that $ACDM$ are concyclic and $ABNE$ are concyclic. Now it's just the matter of angle chasing. Remember about tangent-chord and inscribed angles equality.

If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It leads to a very nice solution. However, can you tell me what was your motivation for proving $ACDM,ABNE$ are cyclic?

Comment: I was just looking at the points and guessing which of them could possibly be concyclic. There isn't any deep motivation beyond that.